# How to use FindChessboardCorners

Tags: c#, emgucv, opencv3.0

i am using the new EmguCV 3.0.0 alpha to detect a chessboard with webcam and have an understanding problem with the corners matrix.

```
        Size patternSize = new Size(5, 4);
        Matrix<float> corners = new Matrix<float>(1, 2);

        bool find = CvInvoke.FindChessboardCorners(grayFrame, patternSize, corners, CalibCbType.AdaptiveThresh | CalibCbType.FilterQuads);
        CvInvoke.DrawChessboardCorners(grayFrame, patternSize, corners, find);
        if (find)
        {
            Console.Write(corners.Size);
        }
```

The chessboard will be detected and shown correct!

But, how big must be the size of the corners matrix and how do i extract the corner positions?

All samples i found on internet are using older versions of EmguCV and there is a complete different syntax now. I would use the older version but the newer alpha is much faster and timing is a big issue in my app.

Comment: Hi, forgive me plz. i'm new here.

Answer (score 6):

The [`CvInvoke.FindChessboardCorners` Method](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/b0a42bbe-419c-18d2-16b9-77d390042133.htm) has this signature<sup>1</sup>:

```
public static bool FindChessboardCorners(
    IInputArray image,
    Size patternSize,
    IOutputArray corners,
    CalibCbType flags = CalibCbType.Default|CalibCbType.AdaptiveThresh|CalibCbType.NormalizeImage
)
```

The third parameter is of type [`IOutputArray`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/db43bb4b-e177-c2c0-9a2f-80193cf5dc2f.htm)<sup>2</sup>. I do not understand why they introduced these super generic input/output interfaces that are implemented by various classes that cannot be used interchangeably.

You are right, the [`Matrix`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0-rc1/document/html/ec1c8c3f-a99c-a082-e794-bb74db961c60.htm) class does implement that interface (via super class [`CvArray`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0-rc1/document/html/7fc0991d-4a1a-4010-3c3f-f68fcf148838.htm)) and thus your code compiles.
However, `CvInvoke.FindChessboardCorners` is supposed to return a few points (depending on the size of the pattern). I googled for classes that implement `IOutputArray` and found [`VectorOfPoints`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0-rc1/document/html/05a55c58-b440-ca74-439c-f288410e692f.htm). That kind of made sense to me, more so than using a `Matrix`.

I hacked together a little console app for calibration that reads all image files from a directory and detects the corners in them, because for me it makes more sense to capture the images beforehand.

That should give you a starting point:

```
public class Calibration
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // chessboard pattern size
        Size patternSize = new Size(9, 7);

        // for each image, have one Image object and one VectorOfPoints
        // for many images have a List of each
        List<VectorOfPoint> corners = new List<VectorOfPoint>();
        List<Image<Gray, Byte>> images = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();

        // get paths to image files
        string[] imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\your\directory", "*.jpg");

        // for every image
        foreach (string imageFile in imageFiles)
        {
            // create new image object from file path
            var image = new Image<Gray, byte>(imageFile);
            images.Add(image);

            // create new list of corner points
            var cornerPoints = new VectorOfPoint();
            corners.Add(cornerPoints);

            // find chessboard corners
            bool result = CvInvoke.FindChessboardCorners(image, patternSize, cornerPoints);

            // some debug output
            Console.WriteLine("=== " + Path.GetFileName(imageFile) + " === " + result);

            if (!result)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // list points
            foreach (Point cornerPoint in cornerPoints.ToArray())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cornerPoint.X + ", " + cornerPoint.Y);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

For some reason I could not get `CvInvoke.DrawChessboardCorners` to execute. It did not finish executing the function in a reasonable amount of time. That's why I printed the results to `Console`, which looks like this for me:

[image]

I verified a few visually in an image editor and they seem to be correct.

### tl;dr

Pick an appropriate type that can represent a **list of points** and that implements `IOutputArray` like `VectorOfPoints` for example.

---

<sup>1</sup> some say the return type is not included in a signature so calling the above a signature might be total nonsense, but you still get the idea when I say "*signature*".

<sup>2</sup> now that's some useful documentation!

Answer (score 1):

CvInvoke.DrawChessboardCorners works after changing `VectorOfPoint` to `VectorOfPointF`

```
public class Calibration
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // chessboard pattern size
        Size patternSize = new Size(9, 7);

        // for each image, have one Image object and one VectorOfPoints
        // for many images have a List of each
        List<VectorOfPoint> corners = new List<VectorOfPointF>();
        List<Image<Gray, Byte>> images = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();

        // get paths to image files
        string[] imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\your\directory", "*.jpg");

        // for every image
        foreach (string imageFile in imageFiles)
        {
            // create new image object from file path
            var image = new Image<Gray, byte>(imageFile);
            images.Add(image);

            // create new list of corner points
            var cornerPoints = new VectorOfPointF();
            corners.Add(cornerPoints);

            // find chessboard corners
            bool result = CvInvoke.FindChessboardCorners(image, patternSize, cornerPoints);

            // some debug output
            Console.WriteLine("=== " + Path.GetFileName(imageFile) + " === " + result);

            if (!result)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // list points
            foreach (Point cornerPoint in cornerPoints.ToArray())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cornerPoint.X + ", " + cornerPoint.Y);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```